# Setting priority branching through pyomo for Baron solver

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I am using Pyomo in Python together with the MINLP solver 'BARON'. 
I have achieved to get it running and pass options (e.g. maxTime) to the solver via pyomo.

In the baron manual, they explain the option to set branching options within pyomo:
"Branching priorities (optional): Branching priorities can be provided using the keyword BRANCHING PRIORITIES. The default values of these parameters are set to 1. Variable violations
are multiplied by the user-provided priorities before a branching variable is selected.
A sample branching priorities section follows:
    `BRANCHING_PRIORITIES{
    x3: 10;
    x5: 0; }"`

**How can I implement this through pyomo as I cannot set it through `solver.option[x1]=1` ?**

The Pyomo Online Documentation 5.1.1 refers to suffixes and an interface with the AMPL for setting the priorities of branching in general. I have not understood suffixes yet and I would appreciate some help with which lines to include in my code to set a priority to a certain variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which interface in Pyomo are you using to call Baron? Do you have standalone BARON installed, or is it through AMPL or GAMS?

Comment: I am using BARON directly through pyomo: solver=SolverFactory("baron")

Answer (score 0):

This may come a bit late but hopefully can help others facing the same issue.
I found this from a test file in the Pyomo source code.
I tested it with the direct BARON shell and it worked.

```py
import pyomo.environ as pe

m = pe.ConcreteModel()

m.y = pe.Var()
m.x = pe.Var()

m.priority = pe.Suffix(direction=pe.Suffix.EXPORT)
m.priority[m.y] = 2
m.priority[m.x] = 1

...
```